# How to export sql to PDF in php, I have generate an error

Tags: php, mysql, database, export

How to fix this error to export sql to PDF. I have generated an error. Can someone provide me with the example code

```php
<?php
define('path','fpdf/font/');
require('fpdf/fpdf.php');
include 'connection.php';
$pdf=new FPDF();
$pdf->Open();
$pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(false);
$pdf->AddPage();
$y_axis_initial = 25;
$pdf->SetFillColor(232, 232, 232);
$pdf->SetFont('Arial', 'B', 12);
$pdf->SetY($y_axis_initial);
$pdf->SetX(25);
$pdf->Cell(30,6,'Complaint',1,0,'L',1);
$pdf->Cell(30,6,'Date',1,0,'L',1);
$pdf->Cell(30,6,'Text',1,0,'L',1);
$pdf->Cell(30,6,'Polar words',1,0,'L',1);
$pdf->Cell(30,6,'Source',1,0,'L',1);
$pdf->Cell(30,6,'Company id',1,0,'R',1);
$y_axis = $y_axis + $row_height;
$fromdate=$_REQUEST['i_name'];
$todate=$_REQUEST['s_name'];
$fromdate=$_REQUEST['address'];
$todate=$_REQUEST['city'];
$fromdate=$_REQUEST['contact'];
$result=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT i_name,s_name,address,city,contact FROM s_reg WHERE limit='1'") or die(mysql_error());
$i = 0;
$max = 25;
$row_height = 6;
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
  if ($i == $max)
  {
    $pdf->AddPage();
    $pdf->SetY($y_axis_initial);
    $pdf->SetX(25);
    $pdf->Cell(30,6,'i_name',1,0,'L',1);
    $pdf->Cell(30,6,'s_name',1,0,'L',1);
    $pdf->Cell(30,6,'address',1,0,'L',1);
    $pdf->Cell(30,6,'city',1,0,'L',1);
    $pdf->Cell(30,6,'contact',1,0,'L',1);
    $y_axis = $y_axis + $row_height;
    $i = 0;
  }
  $complainant = $row['i_name'];
  $date = $row['s_name'];
  $complainttext = $row['address'];
  $complainttitle = $row['city'];
  $polarwords = $row['contact'];
  $pdf->SetY($y_axis);
  $pdf->SetX(25);
  $pdf->Cell(30, 6, $i_name, 1, 0, 'L', 1);
  $pdf->Cell(30, 6, $s_name, 1, 0, 'L', 1);
  $pdf->Cell(30, 6, $address, 1, 0, 'L', 1);
  $pdf->Cell(30, 6, $city, 1, 0, 'L', 1);
  $pdf->Cell(30, 6, $contact, 1, 0, 'L', 1);
  $y_axis = $y_axis + $row_height;
  $i = $i + 1;
}

$pdf->Output('report.pdf','F');

if($pdf->Output('report.pdf','F'))
{
  echo "Report Created Successfyully CLick to view";
}
else
{
  echo "failed to create Report";
}

$pdf->Output();
?>
```

Comment: **what error** and where is it

Comment: Please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
 and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)
 and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I sorted out the repetition in the question and indented the code so people can see what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell us what the error is. One thing I can see, though, is that at the end of the code you've got

```
$pdf->Output('report.pdf','F');

if($pdf->Output('report.pdf','F'))
{
   ...
```

So you're calling the Output function twice.

If I were you I'd go to the [fpdf documentation](http://www.fpdf.org/) and work through the examples slowly, adapting them until you get what you want.